# Error in runs test: "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Tags: r

I'm fairly new to R and I'm trying to simulate some data, fit it to a model, and do a runs test of the residuals. However, I get a strange type error when performing the runs test.
Here is my code:

```
library(TSA)
d = arima.sim(list(ma=c(0.5)), n=5000)
model = arima(d, order=c(0, 0, 1), include.mean=FALSE)
runs(model$residuals)
```

The error is:

```
Error in if (pvalue > 0.5) pvalue <- 1 - pvalue : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: It seems to vary but I think there is probably some sort of overflow that happens somewhere in the code.  For the most part it happens to me if I try to use `runs` using a vector of length 1035 or greater.  Sometimes 1035 values works but I don't know what would cause this exactly

Comment: And would the downvoter care to comment?  They provided example code and the answer definitely isn't obvious...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this package but I can tell that either your data is a particular case or this package (runs function at least) needs a re-review.

```
pdf <- pdf/sum(pdf)                  # pdf contains Inf, so becomes NaN
mu <- 1 + 2 * n1 * n2/(n1 + n2)
if (r1 <= mu)                        # This is verified
    pvalue <- sum(pdf[(1:l2) <= r1]) # pvalue is not calculated, pdf is all NaN
if (r1 > mu)                         # there should be some R versions without else...
    pvalue <- sum(pdf[(1:l2) >= r1])
if (pvalue > 0.5)                    # This gives you the error! pvalue is all NaN
    pvalue <- 1 - pvalue
```

few lines above pdf gets the Inf values:

```
  for (i in seq(4, l2, 2)) {         # when i is 166 pdf gets its first Inf value
    r <- (i - 2)/2
    f[r + 1] <- (n1 - r) * (n2 - r)/r/r * f[r]
    pdf[i] <- f[r + 1]
  }
```

I can't go any further cause I don't know neither how such data is supposed to look like nor the results you should get from such function. Try to give a look yourself into the function, I had enough :-) the missing else in the code above is not the only odd thing into it. Hope that helped

Comment: @tba Have you had any improvements?